# Simple eth sending tx won't work

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix

Why doesn't this work on remix? It compiles the contract but when you execute 'f' it reverts back the tx and sends the error message.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Testing44{

uint256 amount = 1000000000000000000;
address payable recipient;

constructor(address payable _addr){
    recipient = _addr; 
}

function f() public payable {
    //require(msg.value == amount, 'error msg');
    recipient.transfer(amount);
}

}
```

Comment: My guess is that the contract doesn't have enough balance to transfer

Comment: Yes, I agree completely. I'm using the remix IDE and using the dummy addresses that come with it. When I run address(this).balance, it returns 0. But I have no way to add fake value to the address, is there a way to add this fake value?

Comment: It's not very *fake*, since you are using the native asset of the blockchain you are interacting with - your account just happens to have lots of the asset in advance. Anyway, you can simply send the `value` to the function, since it's  `payable`

Comment: implement a `recieve()` function (it can be empty) and send your contract ETH

Comment: Oh wait, you're expecting `recipient.transfer()` to send your eth to the contract?

Comment: Yes, I want to send eth from the contract address to a specified address that was provided in another function. I don't want to manually enter any amount